# Methylation Data for Erythrocytes (Red Blood Cells)?

Tags: red-blood-cell, data, dna-methylation

Why is it that white blood cells (leukocytes) are highly characterized in DNA methylation pure cell line profiling, but I can't find any profiles of red blood cells (erythrocytes)? Is blood considered a pure tissue type?

I'm following the deconvolution of DNA methylation data by cell type (white and red), but I can't do this without pure cell line methylation data. Can anyone help me understand either:

1. Why red blood cell DNA methylation data has not been purified and collected yet.

OR if it has...

2. Where can I access the methylation data for red blood cells (erythrocytes)?

Thanks so much for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is relatively simple: Mature [erythrocytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_blood_cell) do not have a nucleus and thus you cannot study methylation patterns there. You can do this in young, developing erythrocytes which still have their nucleus.